# How to end-to-end test Stripe's new Checkout Sessions

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm looking for a way to set up integration tests for my application that uses Stripe's new(er) [Checkout Sessions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions).

The general workflow is:

1. POST `/backend/create-session`

> returns a `checkout session ID`

2. User would complete the purchase on stripe's domain

> this is the part I'm unable to automate

3. Stripe redirects back to my website with the session ID

> POST `/backend/fulfill-session-id/$SESSION_ID`

I'm able to set up a test for **step 1**, and check that the session is created successfully.

I'm unable to take a given session ID and tell stripe to pretend it has been paid successfully which is preventing me from testing **step 3**

Any way to automate step 2 without adding browser to the mix?

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is to not test Stripe's systems, but to test your own.

Instead of actually redirecting to Stripe Checkout in your code you should mock success and failure states instead.

Comment: I agree, but I don't want to recreate Stripe's different possible outcomes based on the different combination of products/subscriptions. I'd rather run an end-to-end test and leave them to manage the purchase state. I want to confirm that I'm reading/updating the correct data but can not without completing the purchase.

Comment: Well there are 3 possible end states of Stripe Checkout: 1. Redirect failed and error is given in promise (https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout) 2. Payment is successful and user is redirected to `success_url` 3. Payment is cancelled and user is redirected to `cancel_url`. In which case you only need to test the failure in 1 and that the URLs for 2 and 3 exist and are accessible.

Comment: If it's the webhook you want to test, you can trigger `checkout.session.completed` with the Stripe cli for testing: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli

Answer (score 0):

The stripeCLI can be used to resend events - https://stripe.com/docs/cli/events/resend

A quick approach to achieve 3 is to

1. Manually complete 2, noting the event ID from the [Stripe events dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/events)
2. Use the CLI to pretend that the session has been paid successfully:

   `stripe events resend the_event_id`